# Why do I get "Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a javafx project and I get always "Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
I tried everything, but nothing heleped. At first the fxml file wasn't in the same package as the java file, but after placing it to the same package the problem remained. here is my code:

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Lotto extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LottoNezet.fxml"));
        
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Lott program");
        stage.show();
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

And here is the whole exception

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/gerg/eclipse-workspace/FXXMLProjekt/bin/application/LottoNezet.fxml:12

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Lotto.start(Lotto.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lotto.LottoNezetController
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application application.Lotto
```

And here is the fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="lotto.LottoNezetController">
    <children>
      <Pane id="basePane" fx:id="basePane" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="400.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#ebfffd" height="315.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="410.0" />
            <Text layoutX="94.0" layoutY="69.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Írj be 5 számot 1 és 90 között!">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Calibri Light" size="18.0" />
               </font></Text>
            <Text layoutX="161.0" layoutY="43.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="LOTTÓ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="BATAVIA" size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
              <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="264.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Sorsolás!" textFill="#8d0000">
               <font>
                  <Font size="19.0" />
               </font></Button>
            <HBox layoutX="37.0" layoutY="74.0" spacing="40.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="input1" fx:id="input1" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
                  <TextField id="input2" fx:id="input2" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
                  <TextField id="input4" fx:id="input4" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
                  <TextField id="input3" fx:id="input3" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
                  <TextField id="input5" fx:id="input5" layoutX="293.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="1.0" left="1.0" right="1.0" top="1.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <HBox layoutX="48.0" layoutY="163.0" spacing="60.0">
               <children>
                  <Label id="label1" fx:id="label1" graphicTextGap="5.0" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="129.0" />
                  <Label id="label2" fx:id="label2" layoutX="88.0" layoutY="129.0" />
                  <Label id="label3" fx:id="label3" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="129.0" />
                  <Label id="label4" fx:id="label4" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="129.0" />
                  <Label id="label5" fx:id="label5" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="129.0" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <Label id="resultLabel" fx:id="resultLabel" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="260.0" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#fc0000" textOverrun="CENTER_WORD_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <Text layoutX="100.0" layoutY="147.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sorsolt számok:" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="200.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Calibri" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane id="alertPane" fx:id="alertPane" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="400.0" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" fill="#cae5ff" height="123.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Label id="alertText" fx:id="alertText" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="96.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="76.0" prefWidth="209.0" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
            <Button id="alertButton" fx:id="alertButton" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAlertButton" text="OK" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Is there something unclear about "ClassNotFoundException: lotto.LottoNezetController"?

Comment: In JavaFX, the `InvocationTargetException` is almost **never** the actual cause of the error. You need to look further down the StackTrace and read all of the lines starting with "Cause by:"  In your case, the actual error is a `ClassNotFoundException` and that should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: The real error is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lotto.LottoNezetController`. That class name is specified by your `fx:controller` attribute. Does that class actually exist? Did you mistype the name in the FXML file? Did you put the source file in the correct place so that whatever IDE and/or build tool you use actually includes it?

Comment: It was my fault: that was the first time Isaw this kind of exception, and I didn't read it through.